# How to properly implement repository in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

Being new to flutter and dart, I am looking for ways to structure my projects. I have found that the Repository pattern made its way to dart (I have a strong Java background), but I have found that there's not the necessary tools yet to properly implement a repository.

How I would normally approach this is to first create the simple straightforward methods. I ended up with the following dart code:

```
abstract class CategoryRepository {
  Future<List<Category>> getCategories();

  Future<Category?> getCategoryById(String id);
}
```

All is good. But now imagine I have a PostRepository, and I only want to return posts of a specific category? I am missing a standardized way in flutter how to add conditions to my repository select methods. I cannot believe nobody has written something for this purpose before so I am doubting whether I am on the right track here. Maybe my Java background is throwing me off.

In Java (specifically Spring JPA) I am used to specifications, predicates and criteria as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#specifications).

In .NET you can implement select methods of a repository pattern with the Expression class which allows you to use LINQ to add select criteria as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-6.0).

For Flutter or Dart, what would be the equivalent? Or am I on the wrong track?
I have found the [flutter_repository](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_repository) package, but it is deprecated (without a reason). Looking at the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_repository/latest/flutter_repository/Specification-class.html) it indeed had *Specifications* which are used to add conditions. This would be exactly what I expect/need, but again it's deprecated.

This is where I cannot find the information publicly anymore and am questioning "how to properly implement repository in flutter/dart", hence the reason for posting this.